# How to get the Android Gradle plugin and Gradle compatible with each other?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am new to Android Studio and I have encountered this problem[image]

I have these information:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the methods mentioned with the error?

Comment: If you're new to Android Studio try using the stable versions, before moving to Canary or the Beta versions. Just like what the error says in red.

I use Android Studio 3.0.1, my Android plugin version is 3.0.1, while yours is at 2.1.3, a plugin version used in the old v2s of Android Studio. Each new version of Android Studio has their own Android Plugin Version, which you need to update respectively. With what @AnuraagBaishya mentioned the methods to update them are on those links included with the error.

Comment: Yes, I would also suggest you move to a stable version. I am using 3.0.1 too myself